# Querying SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to fetch a person's account balance from a database table in SQL Server.

I've created an SQL command that uses a person's card ID to find out their account ID, then check the balance in another table.

I think I'm missing something - Class1.cardNumber is the card number chosen when you log in.

ok full details is theres 2 forms the first form is a login for an atm that works perfectly i then put a class variable in to capture the cardnumber used in the first form (class1.cardNumber) then i created a command that goes a little like

SELECT CARDDetails, CustomerDetails (bit different names)
then its the link between the 2 using the CustomerNumber
WHERE (balance = @ balance) AND (cardNumber = @ cardNumber) AND (CustomerNumber = @ customerNumber)

this is the only code really in the sheet to sorry about the slow update.

```
sqlCommandBalance.Connection.Open();
sqlCommandBalance.Parameters["@accountID"].Value = Class1.cardNumber;
SqlDataReader readdata = sqlCommandBalance.ExecuteReader();
string balanceDB = "";

while (readdata.Read())
{
    balanceDB = readdata["@balance"].ToString();
}

sqlCommandBalance.Connection.Close();
sqlCommandBalance.Connection.Dispose();

textBalance.Text += " " + balanceDB.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm going to have a stab at rewriting that.

Comment: Okay, rewrote it. You're going to need to provide a bunch more information - first of all, where's the query? What do the tables look like? Please edit your question further with more information. I'd act fast if you don't want your question to get downvoted and/or closed!

Comment: Why is balanceDB a string?  Where do you set the command type or stored procedure name?  What is the stored procedure?  You don't check if any row were returned.   No try catch to see if an error was thrown.

Comment: @tomfanning thanks for the help so far have edit it abit if you need anymore details feel free to ask i'll be here all night

Comment: It's homework. I'm not going to answer the question for you. But I might be able to help guide you to the solution yourself. What you typed isn't an SQL statement, and you've not provided the table definitions. Impossible to help if you don't show us the tables.

Comment: oh ok obviously im missing alot then thanks for the help anyway :) @tomfanning

Comment: Dude, happy to help, but we need more info than you're giving!

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant `readdata["balance"].ToString()`, not "@balance".

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, yet, because there's not enough information.

But this is the sort of pattern you want to be using to safely achieve what you're doing.

```
var resultValues = new List<string>();

using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("server=myserver;database=mydb;integrated security=sspi;"))
using (SqlCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
{
    dbConn.Open();
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE anotherField LIKE @p1";
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "somevalue");

    using (SqlDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            resultValues.Add(reader["myField"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)reader["myField"]);
        }
    }
}
```

or if your query will only ever return one row,

```
double result;

using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection("server=myserver;database=mydb;integrated security=sspi;"))
using (SqlCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
{
    dbConn.Open();
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE anotherField LIKE @p1";
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "somevalue");

    using (SqlDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            result = reader["myField"] == DBNull.Value ? -1 : Convert.ToDouble(reader["myField"]);
        }
    }
}
```

When you come back with more information, we might be able to help with getting this working.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not getting an answer for 'balanceDB' it means that

```
while (readdata.Read())
```

didn't trigger. So it means you're not getting any results. Check that you're running the correct SQL function and you're passing the right parameter. The code itself looks ok to me (a bit messy though).

Can you trace it to see if this is the case?

Added: Also you should probably close your connection in finally. If you throw an exception in there you'll keep the connection open.

Comment: Will try that thanks guys appreciate the help my command at the moment for a something like SELECT  CARD( forgot name on train atm ) , ACCOUNTS

Comment: This is homework, isn't it Rhys?

Comment: @tomfanning its an assignment yes